# Google App Engine with no authentication

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I set up an app with no authentication on google application.

I built and deployed it, but now if someone goes to myapp.appspot.com they are asked to login to my google apps account?

How do I make it 'public'?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python...

You are either requiring login in configuration in app.yaml:https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status

And/or inside your application code. In python it would be @login_required decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify access in your app.yaml or in the web handlers
[see link here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig)

The default is "public"